# Firebase (web) creating/updating users different from current

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'd like to know if it's possible, from website, to create/update firebase users different from the one signed-in: in other words without using console.

[Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) seems to mention creating/updating only for the current user; if that's possible for other users too can anybody kindly address me to some docs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, a web-based application could create and update a different user's profile, but the user performing these actions would need to authenticate as the user they want to manipulate.

It sounds like you're looking for the [Firebase Admin Auth SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/) though:

> You can use the Admin SDK to manage your users or to manage authentication tokens. [...]
>
> **User Management**
>
> It is not always convenient to have to visit the Firebase console in order to manage your Firebase users. The admin user management API provides programmatic access to those same users. It even allows you to do things the Firebase console cannot, such as retrieving a user's full data and changing a user's password, email address or phone number.

This SDK does however need to be developed on a Node.js, Java or Python server or through [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) in order to be secure, but you could write a web frontend that then integrates with this server.

By way of example, [creating a user through the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) in Node.js, you can:

```
admin.auth().createUser({
  email: "user@example.com",
  emailVerified: false,
  phoneNumber: "+11234567890",
  password: "secretPassword",
  displayName: "John Doe",
  photoURL: "http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png",
  disabled: false
});
```

Comment: Nice answer Grimthorr. Thanks for helping our fellow Firebase developers!

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, I'm honoured! Thanks for helping develop a great service.

Comment: thanks @Grimthor, it's just what i was looking for.
i'll dive into that doc ;-)